# Titanium Hyperloop app does not compile due to too small libhyperloop.a lib file

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-hyperloop, hyperloop

I can't compile my titanium + hyperloop application. The compiler complains about the filesize of my libhyperloop.a, which is 2 bytes. Does this mean the file is corrupt, and does someone knows a workaround? I have inspected the file in both hyperloop 1.1.0 and 1.2.0 and both have the same file size.

`ld: file too small (length=2) file '/Users/david/Projects/app/modules/iphone/hyperloop/1.1.0/libhyperloop.a' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Can it be that my libhyperloop.a is corrupt? And does someone knows where to obtain a fully functional version of the hyperloop module?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this @davidcyp ?

Comment: Actually I can't remember anymore because it was a timeboxed proof-of-concept. But I know my former colleague is using hyperloop frequently and is quite happy about it. I will ask him if he remembers the issue.